# How to use global variable inside JavaScript closure?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I wrote a custom menu toggle code like below:

```
var menu_trigger = $('.has-submenu > .nav-link');
menu_trigger.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var this_menu        = $(this);
    var this_menu_parent = this_menu.parent('.has-submenu');
    var this_submenu     = this_menu.find('.submenu');

    if( this_menu_parent.hasClass('active') ) {
        this_submenu.slideUp('500');
        this_menu_parent.removeClass('active'); // <--- HERE
    } else {
        this_submenu.slideDown('500');
        this_menu_parent.addClass('active'); // <--- AND, HERE
    }
});
```

The HTML is like below:

```
<li class="has-submenu active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Parent Menu</a>
    <div class="submenu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/child-1">Child 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/child-2">Child 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/child-3">Child 3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Along with them I'm using some CSS to display none, and with the `.active` class, display block etc.

It's working just fine. But using CSS method, I'm actually loosing the sliding effect, you know. When the `.active` class is gone, the CSS triggers, and the submenu is already gone, so there's no visible sliding effect.

It can be solved by a callback to `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` easily. So I tried this:

```
if( this_menu_parent.hasClass('active') ) {
    this_submenu.slideUp('500', function() {
        this_menu_parent.removeClass('active'); // <--- HERE
    });
} else {
    this_submenu.slideDown('500', function() {
        this_menu_parent.addClass('active'); // <--- AND, HERE
    });
}
```

But as you can see the variable `this_menu_parent` is not correctly called inside the closure, hence it is not working. In PHP, we use the `use` notation, like `function(use global_var) { return global_var * 30 }`, but that's not working for JavaScript.

How can I call global variables inside JavaScript closure?

Comment: That variable is not global, *nor does it need to be*. Your code should work as is. Are you sure that line isn't actually working, and instead simply not having the effect you expect it to?

Comment: I tried `console.warn('inside callback');` inside the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` callbacks, they aren't triggering at all. I tried removing CSS to know whether they are causing any issue. But `slide...` is not working at all with this syntax.